# I am having a CORS error when getting image with Laravel 10

Tags: php, angular, laravel, cors, laravel-10

I have an API with Laravel 10 and I am trying to get an image I have saved in the public/images folder.

This is my function in the controller:

```
public function show()
{
    $imageUrl = asset('images/myimage.png');
    return response()->json(['imageUrl' => $imageUrl]);
}
```

This is my API:

```
Route::get('images', [ImageController::class, 'show']);
Route::post('images', [ImageController::class, 'store']);
```

Using POSTMAN, the response to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/images` is:

```
{
    "imageUrl": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/images/myimage.png"
}
```

And if I open that url with POSTMAN or the browser, I can see the image perfectly.
However, when I try to get the image in my frontend app (with Angular 15) I am getting a CORS error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/images/myimage.png' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

My cors config file is like this:

```
<?php

return [
    'paths' => ['api/*', 'images/*'],
    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],
    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],
    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],
    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],
    'exposed_headers' => [],
    'max_age' => 0,
    'supports_credentials' => false,
];
```

I also tried to edit the Kernel.php like this but no success:

```
protected $middleware = [
    // \App\Http\Middleware\TrustHosts::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
    \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\HandleCors::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
];
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        // \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class.':api',
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\HandleCors::class
    ],

    'images' => [
        \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\HandleCors::class
    ]
];
protected $middlewareAliases = [
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'auth.session' => \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
    'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
    'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'password.confirm' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class,
    'signed' => \App\Http\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
];
```

In my Angular project, I also added a proxy config file for this API:

```
{
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8000",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "changeOrigin": true
  },
  "/images/*": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8000",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug"
  }
}
```

And the function I use to make the request in Angular:

```
getImage(): Observable<Blob> {
  const headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'image/png' });
  return this.http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/images/myimage.png', { headers, responseType: 'arraybuffer' }).pipe(
    map((response: ArrayBuffer) => {
      return new Blob([response], { type: 'image/png' });
    })
  );
}
```

I have been reading about CORS issues with Laravel, but most of the results are about creating a middleware CORS file or using Fruitcake, which are now not needed because Laravel 10 has the CORS file by default.

Am I missing something? Thanks!

Comment: Have you solved this issue?